# Using hash value in photo gallery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to create a navigation for my photo gallery using hash values.

When I click the "Next" link, I get value of the hash and then post it to the another backend php script using jquery `$.get()` api and also set the new hash value for that link. Everything works fine but the hash doesn't update itself with every click. It usually takes 2 clicks to get the updated hash value.

Can anybody here tell me on how I could go about fixing it.

Answer (score 0):

Update hash manually, using

```
location.hash = '#new_hash';
```